# Setting params with StoredProcedureItemReader Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, batch-processing

I´m kind of new with Spring Batch and I´m wondering if there is a way to read a StoredProcedure with IN parameters.

I have already used StoredProcedureItemReader as follows, but I don´t know how to set params

```
@Bean
    public StoredProcedureItemReader<School> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        StoredProcedureItemReader<School> reader = new StoredProcedureItemReader<>();
            reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
            reader.setProcedureName("SP_CLASS");
            reader.setRowMapper(new SchoolMapper());
        return reader;
    }
```

My StoredProcedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_CLASS(IN classlIDParameter INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM students WHERE classId = classlIDParameter ;
END $$
DELIMITER ;

CALL SP_CLASS(40589);   --Calling the SP
```

Not sure how to put the 40589 from Spring Batch. I already have a file with all the "ClassIds". Not sure what is the best approach for this problem